# When two devices connect via wifi, is the connection 'direct' or are they going through a wifi network?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, migration, migration-assistant

In the documentation for ['How to move your content to a new Mac'](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204350), we see:

> If both computers are using macOS Sierra or later, just make sure that they're near each other and have Wi-Fi turned on. If either is using OS X El Capitan or earlier, connect them to the same network using Wi-Fi or Ethernet.

I presume it's implicit that if both computers are using macOS Sierra or later, they'll connect **directly** to each other (without requiring a separate wifi network)? Is this correct?

The reason I ask is because I currently have access to only slow wifi networks, which would pose a problem with the amount of data needing transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t matter if you have a router or not, the macs will find each other and transfer. Plug a direct ethernet cable if you have it for fastest speeds, however. Your reading is correct - good work picking apart the nuance of direct connection on Sierra.